# Design pattern for action of object mode

Tags: delphi, design-patterns

Assuming I have an object with 2 mode, each mode has its corresponding actions:

Mode 1:

- Do1()
- Do2()

Mode 2:

- Do1()
- Do2()
- Do3()

Note: Do1() and Do2() of Mode 1 and Mode 2 are the similar.

I thought of the state and strategy pattern, but they were not appropriate in this case. This case, no need virtual methods, just inherit. But how to change the mode, it will understand the corresponding method?

Which design pattern is appropriate in this case?

**Update 1:**

I further illustrate the problem, let it be clearer.

```
// Object class
class Object
{
public:
    // Assume [mode] is enum type, and
    // there are 2 values: M1, M2
    mode: CMode;
}
```

The methods for M1

```
void Do1();
void Do2();
```

The methods for M2

```
void Do1();
void Do2();
void Do3();
```

I'm researching how to design a class diagram that can use an object like this:

```
CObject* object;

// The object is in mode 1 (M1).
object.mode = M1;
// On mode 1 (M1), only execute 2 methods.
object -> Do1();
object -> Do2();

// The object is in mode 2 (M2).   
object.mode = M2;
// On mode 2 (M2), can execute 2 methods of mode 1 (M1),
// and another methods.
object -> Do1();
object -> Do2();
object -> Do3();
```

I'm looking to design a class structure to do this, instead of using "if" or "switch-case" as before.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. It's not clear to me at least what you mean. Without that clarity I don't think we can give advice based on a solid foundation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks for your supportive attention. I have updated the post (Update 1).

Comment: If you only want to disable Do3() based on object state then why not put a test in Do3() that would simply return if not in state M2?  Otherwise without some real examples of how you would use the object, its hard to offer more advice.